# Elements shrinking in size on a certain page of the website

Tags: html, css

I am building a portfolio website for practice. The website has 3 sections: homepage, portfolio and contact.

When I go the portfolio page, all the elements on my page (navigational bar, image links, footer) shrink in size but not in terms of pixels. The height of my navbar on the portfolio page is the same as its height in the homepage in terms of pixels, but it is shrunken in size on the portfolio page.

At first I thought it was because the portfolio page is larger than the other two. But it seems to be something else. The portfolio page leads to other sections such as paintings, sketches etc. which are also larger compared to the homepage and contact page but the size of the navbar and everything else is consistent with the homepage and contact page.

How can I make the size of the elements on the porfolio page consistent with everything else?

Please let me know what code to post as I am unsure what will help.

Comment: In this case, a link is likely needed … though that's not really the purpose of a knowledge-base site like this.

Comment: @ralph.m the website is not online.

Comment: check your CSS on your portfolio page and other page. compare them if anything's different or causing it.

Comment: I zoomed in on the portfolio page and now everything is the same size! Don't know when I screwed up the zoom. Anyway thanks for looking into it.